# How to calculate Search Admin Database size?

Tags: 2010, search, capacity-planning

In the section entitled "Calculate Storage Sizing" in the technet article here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg750251.aspx?ppud=4

there are a number of useful formulas for calculating various aspects of the search system.  However, in the section that describes how to calculate the search administration database size, the formula is:

> Multiply **number of items in the index (in millions)** by 0.3. This is the **SearchAdminDBSize**.

Frankly, that doesn't make much sense to me.  Is that in KB?  MB?  GB?  How does the number of items get translated into a size?  Is it widely known that each item in the index is a certain size?  What size is that?

Anyone out there have any insight into this, or know the real formula?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree it's poorly articulated.   The size is in GB.

Get the number of million items, times by 0.3 and that's how many GB.

So if you have 10,000,000 items, then its (10 x 0.3 = 3 GB).   (Note: The least you should allocate is 5 GB.)

Hope that helps, but agree they could have been more clear.